# Nodejs TypeError "is not a constructor"

Tags: node.js

I am working through the course ["Build a Blockchain and Cryptocurrency From Scratch](https://www.udemy.com/course/build-blockchain/) from Udemy. I have no prior experience with NodeJS I have been following along with the instructor's code, but recently hit a snag that I cannot resolve. When trying to build the project to run test scripts via `npm run dev`, I get the following error:

```
/home/OnlyDean/Workspace/udemy_blockchain_course_1/app/index.js:13
const p2pServer = new P2pServer(bc);
                  ^

TypeError: P2pServer is not a constructor
```

Answers I've found online seem to indicate that I'm calling an instance of the class `P2pServer` rather than the constructor of the class itself. This is borne out by the output of `console.log(P2pServer);`, which returns `[Object object]`. I have scoured the code for errors, and compared my code to what the instructor has on the screen. I can't seem to find any differences. Below are my `index.js` and `p2p-server.js` classes, which I think are the only relevant files.

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const Blockchain = require('../blockchain');
const P2pServer = require('./p2p-server');

const HTTP_PORT = process.env.HTTP_PORT || 3001;

const app = express();
const bc = new Blockchain();
//console.log(`Blockchain = ${Blockchain}`)
console.log(`P2pServer  = ${P2pServer}`)
console.log(bc)
const p2pServer = new P2pServer(bc);

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/blocks', (req, res) => {
  res.json(bc.chain);
})

app.post('/mine', (req, res) => {
  const block = bc.addBlock(req.body.data);
  console.log(`New block added: ${block.toString()}`);

  res.redirect('/blocks');
});

app.listen(HTTP_PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${HTTP_PORT}`));
p2pServer.listen();
```

**p2p-server.js**

```
const Websocket = require('ws');

const P2P_PORT = process.env.P2P_PORT || 5001;
const peers = process.env.PEERS ? process.env.PEERS.split(',') : [];

class P2pServer  {
    constructor(blockchain) {
    this.blockchain = blockchain;
    this.sockets = [];
    }

    listen() {
    const server = new Websocket.Server({ port: P2P_PORT});
    server.on('connection', socket => this.connectSocket(socket));

    this.connectToPeers();
    
    console.log(`Listening for peer-to-peer connections on: ${P2P_PORT}`);
    }

    connectToPeers() {
    peers.forEach(peer => {
      const socket = new Websocket(peer);

      socket.on('open', () => this.connectSocket(socket));
    });

    }

    connectSocket(socket) {
    this.sockets.push(socket);
    console.log(`Socket connected`);
    }
}

module.export = P2pServer;
```

Any help resolving this error would be greatly appreciated -- I'm kind of stuck with the course until I can resolve this. Thanks!

Comment: please see the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is at the export of the P2pServer class
should be like this (export**s** and not export):

```
module.exports = P2pServer;
```

Comment: I knew it was something painfully simple. Thank you, kind user.